# Positing div in footer

Tags: html, css, positioning

Hi i don't know how to center div in footer or float it right or left because my footer falls apart.
Here is my code:

```
<div id="footer"><div id="tab_brand"><ul>
<li><a href="#"><img src="footer_slike/dell_footer.png"/></a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><img src="footer_slike/acer_footer.png"/></a></li>
</ul></div>
</div>
```

css code

```
#footer{
background-color:grey;
width:100%;
height:auto;
margin:0;
padding:0;
left:0;
clear:both;
opacity:0.8;
}
#tab_brand{
height:100%;
left: 20px;
border:1px solid white;
}
#tab_brand ul li img{
padding:5px;
}
#tab_brand ul{
display: inline-table;
list-style: none;
height:auto;
width:auto;   
}
```

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "footer falls apart"?

Comment: footer just dissapear

Comment: Add overflow: hidden; to #footer and it will no longer disappear when you float its children.

Comment: it works, thank you veary much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to center `#tab_brand` you need to set a width to it and add "`margin: 0 auto`" to center it.
Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ok7Lyp2n/

Comment: @IvanGorički You should do the same for this one and accept it. :)